# Error parsing GeoJson - parse error - invalid geometry

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.2

I'm trying to parse GeoJSON but getting a parse error. I've validated the GeoJSON using http://geojsonlint.com/ and http://geojson.io/.

Using PostGIS 2.2.2 r14797, this is my SQL command:

```
SELECT st_asgeojson('
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
     "GEO_ID": "0500000US01001",
     "STATE": "01",
     "COUNTY": "001",
     "NAME": "Autauga",
     "LSAD": "County",
     "CENSUSAREA": 594.436000
     },
"geometry":
      {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
                [
                     [ -86.917595, 32.664169 ],
                     [ -86.816574, 32.660117 ],
                     [ -86.713390, 32.661732 ],
                     [ -86.714219, 32.705694 ],
                     [ -86.413116, 32.707386 ],
                     [ -86.411172, 32.409937 ],
                     [ -86.444721, 32.399841 ],
                     [ -86.455616, 32.405807 ],
                     [ -86.462497, 32.378135 ],
                     [ -86.492772, 32.361587 ],
                     [ -86.496774, 32.344437 ],
                     [ -86.532531, 32.338775 ],
                     [ -86.542537, 32.363517 ],
                     [ -86.581873, 32.375019 ],
                     [ -86.595335, 32.361345 ],
                     [ -86.614841, 32.374266 ],
                     [ -86.613453, 32.398584 ],
                     [ -86.619812, 32.406474 ],
                     [ -86.653419, 32.397247 ],
                     [ -86.655597, 32.376147 ],
                     [ -86.683537, 32.353395 ],
                     [ -86.711337, 32.360767 ],
                     [ -86.719028, 32.372059 ],
                     [ -86.717897, 32.402814 ],
                     [ -86.727181, 32.404497 ],
                     [ -86.749981, 32.389105 ],
                     [ -86.778365, 32.394601 ],
                     [ -86.780447, 32.368600 ],
                     [ -86.773163, 32.340728 ],
                     [ -86.798268, 32.308632 ],
                     [ -86.816107, 32.309970 ],
                     [ -86.814912, 32.340803 ],
                     [ -86.812714, 32.365354 ],
                     [ -86.840846, 32.396434 ],
                     [ -86.838731, 32.419437 ],
                     [ -86.843503, 32.433117 ],
                     [ -86.857402, 32.438654 ],
                     [ -86.864856, 32.444280 ],
                     [ -86.870960, 32.465716 ],
                     [ -86.881754, 32.480556 ],
                     [ -86.882694, 32.491883 ],
                     [ -86.890037, 32.508091 ],
                     [ -86.901357, 32.528950 ],
                     [ -86.906106, 32.544756 ],
                     [ -86.899138, 32.564242 ],
                     [ -86.903935, 32.587564 ],
                     [ -86.909512, 32.609588 ],
                     [ -86.911149, 32.627764 ],
                     [ -86.917970, 32.645370 ],
                     [ -86.920236, 32.658868 ],
                     [ -86.917595, 32.664169 ]
                ]
           ]
       }
    }
');
```

I'm receiving the following error.

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "
     {
" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
  Where: SQL function "st_asgeojson" statement 1
```

Any idea what's wrong with our GeoJSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `ST_AsGeoJSON` and giving it a GeoJSON feature as input. `ST_AsGeoJSON` produces GeoJSON geometry from a binary geometry. What you probably want is `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`, which takes a string representing GeoJSON geometry, and produces a binary geometry.

Note that `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` only accepts the geometry part of the GeoJSON feature: the properties are another matter.

```
SELECT st_geomfromgeojson('{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [ -86.917595, 32.664169 ],
            [ -86.816574, 32.660117 ],
            [ -86.713390, 32.661732 ],
            [ -86.714219, 32.705694 ],
            [ -86.413116, 32.707386 ],
            [ -86.411172, 32.409937 ],
            [ -86.444721, 32.399841 ],
            [ -86.455616, 32.405807 ],
            [ -86.462497, 32.378135 ],
            [ -86.492772, 32.361587 ],
            [ -86.496774, 32.344437 ],
            [ -86.532531, 32.338775 ],
            [ -86.542537, 32.363517 ],
            [ -86.581873, 32.375019 ],
            [ -86.595335, 32.361345 ],
            [ -86.614841, 32.374266 ],
            [ -86.613453, 32.398584 ],
            [ -86.619812, 32.406474 ],
            [ -86.653419, 32.397247 ],
            [ -86.655597, 32.376147 ],
            [ -86.683537, 32.353395 ],
            [ -86.711337, 32.360767 ],
            [ -86.719028, 32.372059 ],
            [ -86.717897, 32.402814 ],
            [ -86.727181, 32.404497 ],
            [ -86.749981, 32.389105 ],
            [ -86.778365, 32.394601 ],
            [ -86.780447, 32.368600 ],
            [ -86.773163, 32.340728 ],
            [ -86.798268, 32.308632 ],
            [ -86.816107, 32.309970 ],
            [ -86.814912, 32.340803 ],
            [ -86.812714, 32.365354 ],
            [ -86.840846, 32.396434 ],
            [ -86.838731, 32.419437 ],
            [ -86.843503, 32.433117 ],
            [ -86.857402, 32.438654 ],
            [ -86.864856, 32.444280 ],
            [ -86.870960, 32.465716 ],
            [ -86.881754, 32.480556 ],
            [ -86.882694, 32.491883 ],
            [ -86.890037, 32.508091 ],
            [ -86.901357, 32.528950 ],
            [ -86.906106, 32.544756 ],
            [ -86.899138, 32.564242 ],
            [ -86.903935, 32.587564 ],
            [ -86.909512, 32.609588 ],
            [ -86.911149, 32.627764 ],
            [ -86.917970, 32.645370 ],
            [ -86.920236, 32.658868 ],
            [ -86.917595, 32.664169 ]
        ]
    ]
}');
```